# images will not upload properly from images folder with php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote a function to upload image files from a folder to a web page with PHP. The HTML outputs correctly, but the images do not display. When I check the web console I see an "i" in place of the source for my image. I'm sure what's going on here because I do see the correct amount of broken links just not the image

```
    <?php
    // grabs work.php imgs from imgs folder

    $files = GLOB('imgs/*.*');

    //PRINT_R($files);

    function generateImgs($items) {
    $html = "<div class=\"container\">
                <ul class=\"row\">\n";
    foreach ($items as $item){
        $html .= "<li class=\"col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4\"><img src=\"imgs/$item[0]\"/></li>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</ul> </div>\n";
    return $html;
    }

    echo generateImgs($files);

    ?>
```

After messing around a little and changing

```
     <img src=\"imgs/$item[0]\"/>
```

to

```
     <img src=\"./$item'[0]'\"/>
```

I'm now seeing the whole path to displayed to the `img` in the web console but there is a trail of characters after the file name which are `%27%5B0%5D%27`. This string is at the end of every GET request for the image files.

Comment: Try `<img src=\"imgs/$item\"/>` instead

Comment: That worked man thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```php
foreach ($items as $item){
    $html .= "<li class=\"col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4\"><img src=\"imgs/$item\"/></li>\n";
}
```